# Ionic 4 app is not working as Electron app

Tags: angular, typescript, electron, ionic4

I have created an Ionic 4 capacitor app. It is working fine on the Android studio. But it is not working on Electron. Any clue?

This is how I have converted it to Electron:

> npx cap add electron
>
> ionic build --prod
>
> npx cap copy
>
> npx cap open electron

But it shows a blank app. No home screen.

*home.html*

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-button color="primary" (click)="createFile()">Create a file</ion-button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-button color="secondary" (click)="view()">View</ion-button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this and then works fine.

*index.html*

```
<base href="./">
```

And

*tsconfig.json*

from es2015 to es5

```
"target": "es5",
```

Answer (score 0):

That’s the solution I also succesfully apply